# Failing to create JWT token when entering a custom email claim

Tags: go, token, jwt, jwt-go

I am trying to generate a JWT token using Go and I created the following function. I need to add the email address in jwt but as I do this I get an error saying `key is of invalid type`

```
func GenerateUserToken(expiryHours time.Duration, email string, secretKey string) (string, error) {
    // Create a new token object, specifying signing method and the claims
    // you would like it to contain.
    token := jwt.New(jwt.SigningMethodES256)
    claims := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)
    claims["exp"] = time.Now().Add(time.Hour * expiryHours).Unix()
    claims["email"] = email

    tokenStr, err := token.SignedString([]byte(secretKey))
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return tokenStr, nil
}
```

What could be the reason for this? What mistake am I making?

Comment: You need to pass the correct type of key based on your signing method, which, I think, is `ecdsa.PrivateKey`.

Comment: Have you read this Github Issue ? https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/issues/65

Comment: @BurakSerdar I just need to pass a string key. What algorithm must I select then?

Comment: HMAC methods use a simple string key. Both signer and verifier have to know that secret key.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Could you give a small example as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JWT supports many signing algorithms, and that's a challenge for this particular API: depending on the signing algorithm, it expects to see a key matching that algorithm.

If you take a look at the API docs for this particular library:

https://godoc.org/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go

You'll see `SigningMethodXXX` types. These are signers selected by the signing method you pick. For ES256, it uses `SigningMethodECDSA`:

https://godoc.org/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go#SigningMethodECDSA

If you look at the `Sign` method docs, you'll see that it says:

> For this signing method, key must be an ecdsa.PrivateKey struct

which you can parse from a PEM file using:

https://godoc.org/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go#ParseECPrivateKeyFromPEM

For example:

```
pk, err:= jwt.ParseECPrivateKeyFromPEM(pemData)
tokenStr, err := token.SignedString(pk)
```

This should give you a signed token with ES256.

So, you have to first figure out what kind of key you have. If you have a PEM encoding of a ECDSA key in a string, then use this method to parse it and pass the resulting private key to the signer.

If however you simply have a string secret key (like a password) and you'll share this secret key with the users of the JWT, then you can use a HMAC key. A HMAC key is simply a byte array secret that you share with your users so they can validate that the JWT was signed by you. Simply change the SigningMethod to one of the constants in:

https://godoc.org/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go#SigningMethodHMAC

Then, your code as it is will work with the exception that you have to change the  signing method to something like `jwt.New(jwt.SigningMethodHS256)`